# Custom headerLeft component doesn't replace default, adds instead. Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation-v6

I have the following code

```
        React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
          headerTitle: () => <TripHeaderSummary />,
          headerLeft: () => <FontAwesome size={17} color="white" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} name="chevron-left" />,
          headerRight: () => <NView>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 9, color: "white"}} numberOfLines={1}>ARRIVAL ETA</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: "white", fontWeight: "bold"}}>{trip.dropoffDate}</Text>
          </NView>
        })
      },[])
```

Using headerLeft should replace the default back button on android (left arrow).
What happens instead, is that my custom icon is added to the header, but it's not replacing the default. So I end up with two Icons for headerLeft. Below is a screenshot of y issue. This only happens on android, works fine on IOS.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TglLm.png)

I tried upgrading @react-navigation/native and @react-navigation/native-stack to latest but that didn't solve it

Comment: Have you tried setting ```headerBackVisible``` to false? I believe this will hide the default back button and still show your custom one.

Comment: Thank you, @man517. That worked! Didn't even know there was such an option, first time using 6.x

Comment: @man517 It's been a while, but this helped me reach a solution too, consider posting this as an answer, and Op, you should then accept it as the correct answer